# Unable to view values of variables while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying to debug portions of the current application I'm working on, however when I try and check the value of a property/variable I get the error:

`Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized.`

This is just a regular ASP.NET project.  In some portions of the application I can view the properties and variables perfectly fine.  I haven't figured out what's different about the blocks of code that I can and can not see the values of the variables in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was [documented](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2008/08/16/Func_2D00_eval-can-fail-while-stopped-in-a-non_2D00_optimized-managed-method-that-pushes-more-than-256-argument-bytes-.aspx) on an MSDN blog, as being a size limitation of certain types in certain situations, more details in the link.  I believe it was 256 bytes and/or the total size/count of the number of arguments passed to a function. Sorry to say there does not seem to be a quick fix, but hopefully the MSDN blog entry will help you identify a way to solve your problem.

Comment: I doubt that the 256 byte limitation (or number of arguments) is the most common reason for this error.  The article referenced in the linked article, [Rules of Funceval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/11/15/funceval-rules.aspx) gives a number of other reasons why this can occur.

Comment: This was also in VS2008 RTM, so SP1 might have fixed it.  Also I don't know that it even exists in VS2010.

Comment: FYI, same problem exists in VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

This article, [Rules of Funceval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/11/15/funceval-rules.aspx) gives a number of reasons why this can occur.  If debugging is turned on and optimisation turned off already, there doesn't seem to be much else you can do about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making release builds?  Try changing the configuration to "debug" and see if it improves.

Comment: No, the Solution Configuration is set to "Debug"

Comment: Ensure that all projects that are part of the Solution "Debug" configuration are marked as such. Debug is just moniker, and it's possible to have *Projects* set to "Release" under a solution wide "Debug" configuration. Confusing? Yes.

Comment: I've gone though each of my projects.  They are all set to "Active (Debug)" however I changed them all to "Debug".  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem in two of our WinForm user controls.  In both cases the user controls contain a lot of business logic (2000 and 3000 lines of code respectively) and make use of multiple fairly heavy objects (they have 30+ properties that get populated automatically from the database the first time when one of the properties are accessed).  When you try to step through the (somewhat complicated) validation and saving methods, you get this same message when trying to access object properties.

We have come to the conclusion that the size and complexity of the user control combined with the size and complexity of the objects used and conditional database access just becomes too much for the debugger to handle and that we should probably just do some major refactoring to move most of the business logic out of the user control.  It would be interesting to know if your problem arises from the same kind of situation and whether doing the said kind of refactoring actually does make a difference (we have not had the time and/or courage :) to do so).